# Hiding slide Arrow buttons in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery slider with the next and previous arrow buttons on either side. I want these buttons gone when it turns responsive without affecting the rest of the site I have tried a couple of examples but cant get it to work.

HTML

```
<div id="w"> 
<nav class="slidernav">
  <div id="navbtns" class="clearfix">
  <a href="#" class="previous"><img src="img/arrowprev.png"/></a>

  <a href="#" class="next"><img src="img/arrownext.png"/></a>
</div>      
</nav>
```

CSS

```
/** media queries **/
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  h1 { font-size: 2.4em; line-height: 1.2em; }

 .crsl-item h3 { font-size: 1.65em; }
}

/** clearfix **/
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden;    line-height: 0; height: 0; }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }

html[xmlns] .clearfix { display: block; overflow: hidden; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }


previous {

float: left;
margin-left: -3%;
margin-top: 10%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999999;
opacity: 0.0;
}
.next {

float: left;
margin-left: -3%;
margin-top: 10%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999999;
opacity: 0.0;
}
```

I am at a dead end.

Comment: By 'gone' you mean hide/disappear? Why don't you try display: none; with appropriate media query?

Comment: Yes disappear.  When i add in my media query it doesn't work at all and it affects the horizontal overflow on a mobile view

Comment: What are you adding in media query? I don't see any code which will hide the arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily swap the display property on/off for those two buttons, based on the device resolution. First, set them as visible (display:block). Second, if the screen is less than 660px (in this example), swap the display to none.

```
.previous,
.next {
  display:block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  .previous,
  .next {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to hide the `next` and `prev` button:

first target the window/screen size using `media query` example screen size:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {

  //content here

}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

      //content here

    }
```

second don't forget this meta tag before ending `</head>` tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and try this:

```
     //you can set what value you want in max-width
@media screen and (max-width: 660px) { 

       // use display:none to hide your button when the screen size below 660px     
         .slidernav #navbtns a {display:none}

        }
```

and don't forget the meta tag.